# Find text in big files through searching folders

Tags: search

I don't know why people couldn't understand my question, it was put out enough to understand 99.9%.

Anyhow let me try better. I want to search text in ALL text documents within a folder. Let's say I have a folder called Documents, and inside the documents folder is 1000 .txt files. what I want to do is search certain text through all of those at once.

So I would search the folder for text and it will come up with the text documents that have the contained text within them.

The problem is the folder search feature won't show big text documents (such as 1GB+).

That's what I'm trying to accomplish. Searching for contained text but within big files as well.

Comment: `grep "text" *` where grep is native to *nixes and [available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an os which is linux based ,
then in terminal , cd to the folder in which you are searching and do

```
grep "text" *      (without quotes)
```

suppose you want to search for "harry potter "
then do 
     `grep harry\ potter\  *`
(note that there are 2 spaces at end and one space is escaped by putting slash in front)